# free-jqgrid methods and parameters list?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, free-jqgrid

Is there any where a list of available methods and parameters for free-jqgrid ? I am trying to create a API for asp.net. So I need a list of all methods and options available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `free-jqgrid.d.ts` (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.5/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts)) describes all methods, options and events used in free jqGrid. If you use, for example, Visual Studio Code then you can include the like

```js
/// <reference path="free-jqgrid.d.ts"/>
```

(`free-jqgrid.d.ts` can be prepended with the path) then Visual Studio Code will show you IntelliSense information in JavaScript files (not only in TypeScript files) - see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense).

On the other side I don't understand what you mean with the statement: "I am trying to create a API for asp.net." In general you need only generate JSON data in your ASP.NET code and to write pure JavaScript code. Creating of any API for asp.net could be a wrong way.

Comment: Thank you for the information . I meant I am trying to create a web user control like GridView. Where user will be setting the data by passing the data source . And can set properties like ShowFilters, RowNum,Title (Caption) etc from backend itself . He doesn&#39;t need to have knowledge of the front end . Sending the data source as colNames,colModels will be done by the user control itself .

Comment: @AmeyBanaye: You are welcome! Old web user control, introduced Microsoft on the first steps of ASP.NET, are dead in my opinion since many years. Starting with the first version of ASP.NET MVC Microsoft goes in another direction. Web user control have a lot of disadvantages starting with performance and the fact that you will be not have full control over the code, which will be generated. I know only [telerik](https://www.telerik.com/), who try to hold the old concept. I personally prefer ASP.NET MVC in .NET or .NET Core, but it's your own choice.

Comment: yeah even I agree with that . But team I am working with is not so proficient with MVC so I have to work with user controls and asp.net

Answer (score 1):

I think you were looking bad.

You can see free-jqgrid api methods [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/api-documentation/index.html).

Comment: Thank you .. But I also need the objects such as colModel. The members of that object

Comment: @AmeyBanaye. Description of `colModel` can be found [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.5/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L750-L814).

Comment: [The page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/api-documentation/index.html) was my first attempt to describe all API on one place. The page isn't full and it don't contains details (parameters, types and description) of all methods. Later I created [free-jqgrid.d.ts](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts), which allows to describe much more details of all methods. I try to hold the information from `free-jqgrid.d.ts` up-to-date and extend/modify it on adding of any features in the main code.